# How to determine the new line that occurs in text Field ui

Tags: flutter, dart

i found my self in case that i need to determine of the new line that occurs by text field if width was the reached the max ..

i tried this

```
print((textController.text.contains('\n')).toString());
```

but it does not contains '\n' because the new line come from `textField` Widget its self and not user input

i also tried to use

```
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>> globalKeyForTextField2 = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>();
```

then

```
final textFieldState = globalKeyForTextField2.currentState;
    final currentText = textFieldState!.value;
        print('currentText $currentText');
```

it also does not contains '\n' ..

so i need the way for that so according to it i will manually add the '\n' to my textController ..

i need this case because i want to copy this text to other platform

any suggestion ?

Comment: To be clear, you need know when the line break, right?

Comment: i am scary if i did not understand you well , but yes when the text is expanded to new line simply

Answer (score 0):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76581379/how-to-determine-the-new-line-that-occurs-in-text-field-ui#comment135023198_76581379), you want to obtain the position of the line break present in your `FormTextField`.

You can do this by creating a [`TextPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter-class.html) with the same configuration as the text field's. Then, you call [`layout()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter/layout.html) on it with a correct `maxWidth`, the same as the available space in your text field.

After that, you will be able to use the [`getLineBoundary()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter/getLineBoundary.html) passing a zero text position, which will return you a `TextRange`, which `end` property corresponds to the last character in line.